# Why java's HashMap recheck hashcode inside bucket

Tags: java, hashmap

When HashMap is searching for key it use key's hashcode in 2 places:

1. to choose bucket
2. to find entry inside bucket ([openjdk7 HashMap get method source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l322))

   ```
       public V get(Object key) {
           if (key == null)
               return getForNullKey();
           int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
           for (Entry e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
                e != null;
                e = e.next) {
               Object k;
               if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
                   return e.value;
           }
           return null;
       }
   ```

Why HashMap is checking hashcode inside bucket? Why is it not enough to check only references and objects equality inside bucket?

Comment: It is checking the key's `hashCode()`, not the hashcode of the bucket. It saves on equality tests.

Comment: Because a bucket contains keys with different hashes, an it's faster to compare hashes than to compare keys.

Answer (score 6):

Comparing hash codes (that were already computed, so no need to call the `hashCode()` method again), which is `int` comparison, will often be cheaper than calling `equals`.

Since a bucket may contain keys having different hash codes (for example, in a `HashMap` with 16 buckets, hash codes 1 and 17 will be mapped to the same bucket), comparing hash codes first may save the need to run equals (when the hash codes are not equal to each other).

This is similar to the optimization that checks reference equality (`(k = e.key) == key`) before calling `equals`.